# Can't add element to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an object called `Customer`, that I want to add into my `ArrayList`. The plan is to make a program where I can search for customers and click into their profile. This is the constructor for my object:

```
public Customer(String firstname, 
                String secondname, 
                LocalDate birthdate, 
                String mail, 
                String phonenmbr, 
                String adress,
                String postnumber, 
                String postplace)
```

And this is when I try to place to object into the `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

customerList.add(
new Customer("AARON",
               "SMITH",
               LocalDate.of(1980,01,01),
               "ex@mail.com",
               "92081",
               "Testveien 109A",
               "1234",
               "OSLO"));
```

Multiple markers at this line

> Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this       token
>
> Syntax error on token ";", @ expected
>
> Syntax error on token ";", @ expected

Comment: Constructors with many parameters like that are generally discouraged.  You should consider having a constructor with essential information only, and getters and setters for the rest.

Comment: Post the code with the method inside or is it outside a method?

Comment: I posted the code inside a method, and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not please post your complete code where are you getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have space between 'post' and 'place' at the end as part of constructor argument. That is not valid nomenclature in java.

If its supposed to be single field define it like post_place. If they are two, add type for place as well separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

take a look to `...String post place`) in the `Costumer constructor`... there is an space between  **name** and **parameter**, and this is not allowed ..

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code and it works, did you import `java.util.*` and `java.time.LocalDate`? Are you using java 8?
This is your code and it works: http://goo.gl/VI6Kef